# Задача из муниципального этапа по программированию

Tags: python, олимпиада

Задача имеет в себе 10 тестов. С числами до миллиона компьютер справляется, потом — всё.

###### Задача

Дано некое целое положительное число N. Нужно найти сумму чисел от 1 до N, но все числа должны дважды переворачиваться и незначащие нули должны быть удалены.
То есть есть число — 2300, сначала переворачиваем, получаем — 0032, убираем нули, получаем 32, и опять же переворачиваем, получаем 23. Но, повторюсь, каждое число от 1 до N должно быть так перевернуто. Также у полученной суммы надо найти остаток от деления на 10**9 + 7
Если предоставите решение для больших чисел, буду благодарен.

Помню несколько тестов, на которые вы можете ориентироваться:

| N | ответ |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 36 |
| 19 | 181 |
| 234 | 24984 |

###### Скрипт:

```
def flip(n):
    while n % 10 == 0:
        n //= 10
    return n
n = int(input())
sum = 0
for x in range(1, n+1):
    sum += flip(x)
print(sum % (10**9 + 7))
```

Comment: А у вас что не получилось? В чем возникли сложности?

Comment: Когда числа достигают 10**7, программа начинает считать очень медленно

Comment: Я на 146% уверен, что в задании *сумму* находить не нужно. Только остаток от деления.

Comment: Нет, в этом и вся загвостка

Comment: Не верю © 
Никто в здравом уме на муниципальной олимпиаде не даст задание на большие числа.

Comment: Когда проверят все работы, отправлю. Но дело твое.

Comment: @akimochev Вероятно, вы не поняли, что имел в виду Alexey Ten. По свойствам модуля суммы вы можете брать его после каждого суммирования, тогда числа не станут велики

Comment: Хотя есть метод и пошустрее, не требующий перебора. Ладно, уже три часа ночи, завтра.

Comment: @Alexey Ten так олимпиада по биг дате 

Comment: Не, я прям помню, там было написано: ...сумма будет большая, поэтому найдите остаток от деления суммы.

Comment: А что потом все? Телефон при вводе 12345678 считает примерно две секунды. Что там за компьютер?..

Comment: «сумма будет большая, поэтому найдите остаток от деления суммы» — ну так это и значит что саму сумму вам считать не нужно, а нужен только остаток от деления, а это гораздо проще…

Comment: @AlexeyTen, остаток не влияет на сложность решения. Есть решение за логарифм, которое строит полную сумму. Работает мгновенно, естественно. Единственная незадача - я его "подобрал". Опубликую, когда найду обоснование. Вдруг ошибся? Неудобно будет. :)

Comment: Теоретически не влияет, а практически влияет, т.к. работать с большими числами «дорого»

Answer (score 2):

Если диапазон большой, то перебор всех чисел, конечно, не вариант.

Однако в школе нас учили <s>вычитать и умножать, малышей не обижать...</s>  находить сумму арифметической прогрессии по простой формуле.
Для ряда `1..n` эта сумма будет равна `n*(n+1)/2`.

Так мы получаем сумму всех чисел диапазона, но эта сумма включает и числа с терминальными нулями. Поэтому результат нужно уменьшить на сумму чисел, оканчивающихся нулём, и прибавить сумму чисел этой же выборки, делённых на 10. То же самое (с учётом десятичного порядка) с числами, оканчивающимися на два нуля, на три нуля, и так далее.

Получается, что за логарифм числа (длина его десятичной записи), т.е. практически мгновенно, мы рассчитаем всё, что нужно:

```
def sz(n):
    res = n * (n + 1) // 2
    while n:
        n = n // 10
        res -= 9 * n * (n+1) // 2
    return res % 1000000007
```

Cравнение с функцией автора:

```
print(flipfunc(39457298), sz(39457298))
>>>11370029 11370029
```

Длиииннный диапазон:

```
print(sz(7023530680698209829384502876017846507860760876304750347503489712034))
>>678324285
```

Для Python даже не буду промежуточные результаты считать по заданному модулю, для языков без встроенной поддержки длинных чисел это сделать придётся.

Comment: @akimochev Ну что, разобрались?